# Where do non-audio bluetooth-transferred files go in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: bluetooth, file-transfer

Windows Phone does not seem to be managing files as conveniently as Android. I am confused where do the files that are sent to it via Bluetooth go? Having set the SD card as default storage, I can find music files in `SD Card>Music` folder. Also, videos go to `sd card>Pictures/saved pictures`, but what about other file types like `*.doc`, `*.docx`, *.pdf, `*.exe`  (a handy way to have a crucial small exe at your disposal for certain reasons), etc. Where do they go after transfer over Bluetooth? I want to be able to transfer any file type via Bluetooth and know where they reside after transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows phone stores files like **.doc**,**.docx**,**.pdf**,**.txt** received using Bluetooth at location :

> Phone > Documents

though you have set it to store new files and all apps in SD Card (as SD Card is removable device, for reasons like file(s) being lost, it will save it to phone storage instead SD Card).